Git not working in Windows 11 Powershell (Select an App to open 'git')
I have downloaded git for windows,
git version 2.44.0.windows.1
Which works fine in Windows cmd & Git Bash & Powershell x86 


However when running in Windows Powershell I get the Select an app to open,

Also my environment variables (System) are set to
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\


Have you tried to reboot your PC? Does git.exe work? Can you call it with the full absolute path?

@arch Yes, just done a reboot. still same error persists.
In terms for running the full path works, It does work
PS C:\Users\slevin> & 'C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe' --version
git version 2.44.0.windows.1

You could try to get the path of git from powershell, just to see if it is trying to run the correct thing. https://superuser.com/a/676107/959674

Thanks @Kim for pointing me in the right direction, Was able to resolve the issue.

Running the command
Get-Command -Name git

Seems like it was pointing to the wrong Source in Windows Powershell.
When changing the Environemnt Priority to allow it to be run first or deleting the other git resolved the issue
